# Displaying dashed lines with segments spaced evenly relative to camera plane

Tags: coffeescript, three.js

I am building an engineering tool using three.js as a 3D model editor.

I have created the X, Y, and Z axes using six lines; RGB for XYZ, solid for positive, dashed for negative. Here's the code in CoffeeScript, heavily based on Soledad Penadés' tutorial at soledadpenades.com/articles/three-js-tutorials/drawing-the-coordinate-axes/:

```
buildAxes: (length) ->                                                                             
  axes = new THREE.Object3D                                                                        

  axes.add @buildAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(length, 0, 0), 0xFF0000, false)
  axes.add @buildAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(-length, 0, 0), 0xFF0000, true)
  axes.add @buildAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0, length, 0), 0x00FF00, false)
  axes.add @buildAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0, -length, 0), 0x00FF00, true)
  axes.add @buildAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, length), 0x0000FF, false)
  axes.add @buildAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -length), 0x0000FF, true)
  return axes                                                                                      

buildAxis: (source, destination, color, dashed) ->                                                 
  geom = new THREE.Geometry                                                                        
  mat = undefined                                                                                  
  if dashed                                                                                        
    mat = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial                                                             
      linewidth: 1                                                                                 
      color: color                                                                                 
      dashSize: 3                                                                                  
      gapsize: 3                                                                                   
  else                                                                                             
    mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial                                                              
      linewidth: 1                                                                                 
      color: color                                                                                 
  geom.vertices.push source.clone()                                                                
  geom.vertices.push destination.clone()                                                           
  geom.computeLineDistances() # required for dashed lines                                          
  axis = new THREE.Line geom, mat, THREE.LineSegments                                              
  return axis
```

[Here's the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edBWU.png)

While this looks pretty good, the dashed lines appear messier as they move away from the origin. I would like to have the dashed line segments be of equal length and equal spacing relative to the camera's plane. [Here's a screenshot of SketchUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20l87.png) that shows a similar effect, but with dots.

I think it should be possible to split up a dashed line into many segments that each have dynamic lengths and positions, but that seems like a lot of overhead for a seemingly innocuous improvement. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Try `line = new THREE.LineSegments( geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial() )`. Every pair of vertices in the geometry defines a separate line segment. Space the pairs as you wish. --- Or try an `OrthographicCamera` (three.js r.74)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I apologize for not being more explicit.

I am intending to maintain a perspective view; it seems what I actually need is to define segment length/spacing in terms of screen coordinates, rather than world coordinates. The individual segments should always appear the same length and distance from each other, no matter the perspective.